# How to handle an error with createProcess in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to call a process that may or may not exist on a user's system. If the command doesn't exist, I want to fall through to a different command, but I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried many variations of the following code:

```
-- call.hs
import System.Process
import System.Exit

main = do
  (_,_,_,p) <- createProcess (proc "this_command_does_not_exist" [])
  ExitFailure _ <- waitForProcess p

  -- This line is never printed:
  putStrLn "The command failed"
```

When I run this with `runghc call.hs`, I get the following output:

`call.hs: this_command_does_not_exist: createProcess: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

meaning the program terminates at that line and doesn't continue. How can I handle this error?

Comment: This function probably raises an exception. Use Control.Exception module to handle it.

Comment: Hmm, just tested your code on ideone.com: http://ideone.com/l8U0pT. It ran as you desired. So what platform do you use?

Comment: Oh, I guess it's platform-specific. I was working on this on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`try`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html#v%3atry) from `Control.Exception` to catch the [`IOException`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html#t%3aIOException) that is thrown when the program doesn't exist:

```
import Control.Exception

-- we specialize the signature of "try" to catch only IOException
try' :: IO a ->  IO (Either IOException a)
try' =  try 

main = do
  result <- try' $ createProcess (proc "this_command_does_not_exist" [])
  case result of
        Left ex -> putStrLn $ "error starting: " ++ show ex 
        Right (_,_,_,p) -> putStrLn "started ok"
```